# MongoDB, aggregation result , $out vs forEach

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to append the result to a existing table, 
I am now trying to use this:

```
var result =  db.table.aggregate(...)
result.forEach(
    function(obj) {
        db.result.save(obj)
    }
)
```

but I found this much slower than `$out` operation, how can I save the result as a whole but not erasing existing table?

Answer (score 0):

In first solution you can save $out to outFile and then restore to your new collection.

This process can be written with bash or any programming language with hardly 5 lines of code. :)